# Instance of Array returning error

Tags: javascript

I have a simple check to see if a particular set of keys is an array and if not create it but for some reason the if statement returns an error, this is what I am trying to do:

```
//test data
var i = 0;
var map = new Array(); 
var Data[i]['x'] = 6;
var Data[i]['y'] = 7;

if(!map[Data[i]['x']] instanceof Array){
   map[Data[i]['x']] = new Array();
}

if(!map[Data[i]['x']][Data[i]['y']] instanceof Array){ //error on this line
   map[Data[i]['x']][Data[i]['y']] = new Array();
}
```

The error is:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '6' of undefined`

This error is occuring on the second IF statement. What is the mistake I am making here?

Comment: Can you post a demo to jsfiddle?

Comment: You haven't declared `i`

Comment: oops i forgot to paste i into the question :P

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski http://jsfiddle.net/bH6aG/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first `if` statement:

```
if(!map[Data[i]['x']] instanceof Array)
```

is being parsed as:

```
if((!map[Data[i]['x']]) instanceof Array)
```

At that point, `map[6]` is undefined, so `!map[6]` is `true`, and `true` is not an instance of `Array`. So it doesn't set it to `new Array()`.

Change it to:

```
if (!(map[Data[i]['x']] instanceof Array))
```